# PythonでAPIで複数ページに渡るデータ取得

Tags: python, json, pandas, api

[PythonでAPIで取得したJSONをデータフレーム化したい](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/63096/python%e3%81%a7api%e3%81%a7%e5%8f%96%e5%be%97%e3%81%97%e3%81%9fjson%e3%82%92%e3%83%87%e3%83%bc%e3%82%bf%e3%83%95%e3%83%ac%e3%83%bc%e3%83%a0%e5%8c%96%e3%81%97%e3%81%9f%e3%81%84?noredirect=1#comment69092_63096)
の続きです。

以下のコードで、iについて数値でループさせても同じページが取れてしまいます。
これを回避する方法はありますでしょうか。それとも非対応でしょうか？

```
hb_count = 'http://api.b.st-hatena.com/entrylist/json?sort=count&page='+str(i)
```

また、JSON内のデータの順番(count, linkなど）が順番が一定しないです。（データフレーム化のときに問題を引き起こしているわけではないので別に良いのですが気になります。）

どうぞよろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: リクエスト先URLは正しいものでしょうか？ はてなブックマークのデータを取得しようとしているのであれば、ドキュメントを眺めた限り `entrylist/` を含むURLは見当たらないような気がします。 - http://developer.hatena.ne.jp/ja/documents/bookmark

Comment: はてなブックマーク新着エントリーページの HTML ソースコードを眺めていると、こんな記述が見つかります。`<link rel="next" href="/entrylist/all?page=2">` ですが、`entrylist/all/json` とか `entrylist/json/all` などとしても JSON 形式でのレスポンスを取得できないので、HTML で取得して必要な情報を抽出するしかなさそうです。

Comment: @metropolis APIでは不可能とのこと、了解いたしました。ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 1):

はてなブックマーク API では取得可能なエントリ数が固定されている様なので、Web スクレイピングで行ってみました。予め BeautifulSoup パッケージをインストールしておいて下さい。

**get_entry.py**

```
import requests
import json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def get_entry(url, num_page):
  entry = []
  for p in range(num_page):
    r = requests.get(
      hb_count, params={ 'url': url, 'sort': 'count', 'page': p+1 })
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
    for s in soup.select('div.entrylist-contents-main'):
      atr = s.select('h3.entrylist-contents-title a')[0]
      cnt = s.select('span.entrylist-contents-users a span')[0].text
      entry.append({
        'title': atr['title'], 'url': atr['href'], 'count': cnt })

  return json.dumps(entry)

if __name__=='__main__':
  hb_count = 'https://b.hatena.ne.jp/entrylist'
  url = 'https://newspicks.com/'
  num_page = 3

  json_data = get_entry(url, num_page)
  print(json_data)
```

**実行結果**

```
$ python3 get_entry.py | jq '.'

[
  {
    "title": "グーグルが採用面接で聞く質問リストとは",
    "url": "https://newspicks.com/news/951070/body",
    "count": "1035"
  },
  {
    "title": "元社員らに聞く「エバーノートはなぜ深刻な状況に陥ったのか」(前編)",
    "url": "https://newspicks.com/news/1237596/body/",
    "count": "854"
  },
  {
    "title": "【新】先進国一、勉強しない日本の会社員に明日はあるのか？",
    "url": "https://newspicks.com/news/2647674/",
    "count": "581"
  },
                            :
                            :
```