# JSON-LD を Pandas の DataFrame へ変換する方法

Tags: python, pandas, json

JSON-LDで値を返す RESTful API を使って、`r = requests.get( <API> )` で受け取った
`r` の `type` は `<class 'requests.models.Response'>` です。

[JSON を Pandas DataFrame に変換する](https://www.delftstack.com/ja/howto/python-pandas/json-to-pandas-dataframe/) のページを見ながら真似してみたのですが、エラーとなってしまいます。
`json.loads(r.text)` の引数に何を入れたらよいのかがわかりません。

よろしくお願いいたします。

**コード:**

```py
data_jsn = json.loads(r.text)
df = pd.read_json(data_jsn, orient='index')
```

**エラーメッセージ:**

```py
raise ValueError(msg)
ValueError: Invalid file path or buffer object type: <class 'list'>
```

Comment: `r.text`や`data_jsn`の実態がどんな物か内容をテキストで提示すれば助言や回答を得やすいのでは？

Comment: 質問は見やすさのため最低限、説明の文章とコードやエラーを段落で分けることを意識してみてください。また、[Markdown のコードブロック](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code) を使うとハイライトされてより見やすくなります。

Comment: ちなみにこの記事 [PythonでAPIで取得したJSONをデータフレーム化したい](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/63096/26370) が類似内容と思われます。その質問では具体的なAPIのURLや`r.text`の気になる内容などが提示されていて、回答しようとする人が再現・調査出来るようになっています。

Comment: 皆様、返信ありがとうございます。
【
＜r.textやdata_jsnの実態がどんな物か＞

https://www.odpt.org/
で公開しているデータなのですが、いちおう会員登録しないとみられないデータなので、ネット上に書くのは避けたいです。】

【＜ちなみにこの記事 PythonでAPIで取得したJSONをデータフレーム化したい が類似内容と思われます。＞

ありがとうございます。見てみます。】

Comment: どうも、データそのものに不具合があったようです。（きちんとJSON形式に合致していなかった）